# TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got <class 'rest_framework.fields.CurrentUserDefault'>

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-serializer

Seems I need to apply a dot notation to CurrentUserDefault() object, tried .id but failed

```
class DotPrivateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    tag = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_tag(self,obj):
        queryset=TagPrivate.objects.filter(user=serializers.CurrentUserDefault) # <--TypeError
        return TagPrivateSerializer(queryset).data
```

models.py

```
class DotPrivate(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE       
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=350, blank=True)
    lon = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    lat = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    rating = models.FloatField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0.0), MaxValueValidator(5.0)])
    tag = models.ForeignKey('TagPrivate', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

in the following link in the first answer I found some solution but I do not completly understand it:
['CurrentUserDefault' object has no attribute 'user'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34959221/currentuserdefault-object-has-no-attribute-user)

```
    class TagPrivateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

        class Meta:
            model = TagPrivate
            fields = ('id', 'name')
            read_only_fields = ('id',)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not use `CurrentUserDefault`, this is just a value that the Django serializer will use for a `default=…` parameter, and then later swap for the request user.

You can fetch this from the request in the context, so:

```
class DotPrivateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    tag = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_tag(self, obj):
        queryset = TagPrivate.objects.filter(user=self.context['request'].user)
        return TagPrivateSerializer(queryset).data
```

In the `ModelViewSet`, you will need to pass the user, so:

```
class DotPrivateViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = # …
    permission_classes = # …
    serializer_class = DotPrivateSerializer

    def get_serializer_context(self):
        context = super().get_serializer_context()
        context.update(request=self.request)
        return context
```

Comment: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `name` on serializer `TagPrivateSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `QuerySet` instance.
Original exception text was: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'name'.

Comment: @kubaSpolsky: you likely forgot the `many=True` when constructing the serializwer. You will also need to pass the request as context, so `context={'request': request}`. One of the (very) many reasons to use class-based API views/viewsets.

Comment: Could you indicate me where should I include "context={'request': request}"